# How do I make Line Pay app functional on Blue Stacks

Tags: bluestacks, line

I assume I have to do some control mapping but I can't see what and how to do that. I used the custom controls to make game work but I don't see what is needed for this map. What custom controls are needed for Line Pay App?

Comment: Could you explain more about the problem with Line Pay? Cannot be installed? Crash? Warning/error message? I'm not sure about the control mapping, but payment apps usually disable themselves if run on emulators for security reasons (similar to rooting).

Comment: It doesn't give any messages. It was installed.